# How to print message to the user on package installation?

Tags: debian, packaging, notifications

I want to notify user about important details when package is installed. I've looked at https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#list-of-fields but don't see anything fit for that purpose. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that this is covered earlier in that document, in [Prompting in maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#prompting-in-maintainer-scripts), with:

> Package maintainer scripts may prompt the user if necessary. Prompting must be done by communicating through a program, such as `debconf`, which conforms to the Debian Configuration Management Specification, version 2 or higher.
>
> […]
>
> If a package has a vitally important piece of information to pass to the user (such as “don’t run me as I am, you must edit the following configuration files first or you risk your system emitting badly-formatted messages”), it should display this in the `config` or `postinst` script and prompt the user to hit return to acknowledge the message. Copyright messages do not count as vitally important (they belong in `/usr/share/doc/package/copyright`); neither do instructions on how to use a program (these should be in on-line documentation, where all the users can see them).
>
> Any necessary prompting should almost always be confined to the `config` or `postinst` script. If it is done in the `postinst`, it should be protected with a conditional so that unnecessary prompting doesn’t happen if a package’s installation fails and the `postinst` is called with `abort-upgrade`, `abort-remove` or `abort-deconfigure`.